# Slim 3: How to access user information from request headers

Tags: slim

I am using Slim 3.1 and able to authenticate correctly i.e. able to generate the token and use it for another POST request. Now I want to parse the request header to extract the user information so I can identify which user have sent the request. 
Here is my code to get the token.

```
$app->post('/login/token', function (Request $request, Response $response, 
array $args) {

$input = $request->getParsedBody();
$now = new DateTime();
$future = new DateTime("+10 minutes");
$server = $request->getServerParams();
$jti = (new Base62)->encode(random_bytes(16));
$payload = [
    "iat" => $now->getTimeStamp(),
    "exp" => $future->getTimeStamp(),
    "jti" => $jti,
    "sub" => $input['username']
];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE User_Name= :username";

$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam("username", $input['username']);

$sth->execute();
$user = $sth->fetchObject();

// verify email address.
if(!$user) {
    return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'These credentials do not match our records.']);  
}

// verify password.
if (!password_verify($input['password'],$user->User_Password)) {
    return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'These credentials do not match our records.']);  
}

$settings = $this->get('settings'); // get settings array.

//$token = JWT::encode(['User_ID' => $user->User_ID, 'username' => $user->User_Name], $settings['jwt']['secret'], "HS256");
$token = JWT::encode($payload, $settings['jwt']['secret'], "HS256");
return $this->response->withJson(['token' => $token, 'ACL' => $user->User_ACL]);

});
```

This returns me a token that I send in the following POST request

```
$app->group('/api', function(\Slim\App $app) {
$app->post('/createuser', function (Request $request, Response $response, 
array $args) {

$headerValueArray = $request->getHeader('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION');

return $this->response->withJson(['success' => true,  $token]);
});

});
```

The above POST request gives the following output

{
    "success": true,
    "0": ["Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MzU4Mjk0OTUsImV4cCI6MTUzNTgzNjY5NSwianRpIjoiMWc5ZFM3dUNLbzl1blRQZzBmYjU2diIsInN1YiI6InN5c2FkbWluIn0.vo3FBPhBkhfA2y7AG-afmjfeEhygIYY7lIaaVNX5i5k"]
    }

I need to parse this token to extract the user information to see if its the valid user to perform this operation.In other words, how I can decode the above token.
Any help here will be much appreciated!

Comment: Aren't you already useing firebase JWT library ? Just decode the token using $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));

Comment: I am getting this response 'Type: UnexpectedValueException
Message: Wrong number of segments' when I pass either $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $settings['jwt']['secret'], array('HS256')); or $decoded = JWT::decode($request->getHeaders(), $settings['jwt']['secret'], array('HS256'));  Can you please elaborate what this $jwt carries ?

Comment: It is solved now by using    $headerValueArray = $request->getHeader('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION');
$headerValueArray = str_replace("Bearer ", '', $headerValueArray) ; $decoded = JWT::decode($headerValueArray[0], $settings['jwt']['secret'], array('HS256')); Thanks for all the help!